# Replacement(s) for TeX's paragraph builder using LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, paragraphs, lua

The LuaTeX engine provides a callback that allows you to replace the built-in paragraph builder by your own algorithm. My question is twofold:

- does there exist a lua implementation that fully (or partially) reimplements the normal algorithm that can be used as a basis for paragraph breaking experiences?
- if not (or even if yes) are there any other known uses of this callback?

### Update

Given that my first part of the question was answered in the comments below, i.e., that Taco (I guess) has reimplemented the paragraph builder from TeX (with additions from pdfTeX and Omega/Aleph) in Lua). Can somebody perhaps show how to use this lua script in a simple plain TeX scenario?

In other words how is this applied so that

```
<some luatex setup setting up the appropriate callback to make use of node-ltp.lua>

This is a sample paragraph ....\par

\bye
```

works?

If that is too complicated with plain (as the code seems to draw a lot on ConTeXt specific  material) then something that works with ConTeXt is fine too. After all, all I want to be able to is to see the code in action and be able to do experiments by changing it on the Lua side.

Comment: Yes; Hans Hagen presented one this week at the ConTeXt conference.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Is there any link where we can review that you mentioned?

Comment: @Aradnix The parbuilder code has been part of Context for quite some time. Just check your TeX distribution for the file ``node-ltp.lua``. Of course, the code is [available in the official Git repo](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/tree/master/tex/context/base/node-ltp.lua) as well.

Comment: @phg must have been blind .. of course it is in TL14 ... now I only have to find out how to actually use it ... but it does only answer the first part of my question ... is there anything else?

Comment: @phg  or anybody else: any chance to help with an answer showing how to make this code work?

Comment: That looks so interesting and I wish I had some time playing around with it.

Comment: I've created small lua library which doesn't replace linebreaking algorithm, but calls it multiple times with different parameters, until no overfull boxes are found. it also has simple river detection, see file `latex-pokus.tex`. it's on my github: https://github.com/michal-h21/linebreaking

Comment: @michal.h21 Paulo already pointed me to your work which is cool, though not quite what I'm after as I do want to bake the river detection directly into Knuth/Plass algorithm. Anyway, getting close to make Taco's code work standalone ... few more issues to fix and then I'm there. So far it already compiles on LaTeX and typesets tugboat papers, but there are still a few niggles like handling \vadjust (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205217/10109)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In ConTeXt, you are supposed to use it like this:

```
\starttext
\startparbuilder[basic]
This is a sample paragraph .... \par or more of them
\stopparbuilder
\stoptext
```

and it is supposed to listen to `\tracingparagraphs`.

I say supposed, because the current version has some bugs: continued development of ConTeXt has changed some of the internals and this code, which is hardly ever used, has not been kept up to date. I'll send a message off to the ConTeXt mailing list reporting the problems.

Comment: I'm intrigued: if you've reimplemented the paragraph breaker in Lua, is there a reason it's not used routinely?

Comment: At first, it needed extensive testing. But nowadays it is mostly because of speed I assume.

Comment: yep, it claims `system          > invalid \starttext ... \stoptext structure` and only produces a page number :-) and with additional para tracing it also says `Lua linebreak_filter failed, reverting to default on line 1` so as you say it doesn't quite work yet. Pity. Would be great if that could get resolved on the ConTeXt mailing list and an answer posted here

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Did you add `\starttext` before the given code and `\stoptext` after? Add that standard code for a ConTeXt document makes everything work for me with the TL2014 version of ConTeXt MkIV.

Comment: @JosephWright of course not :-) I trusted this is a complete example, but sure that's my ignorance. Anyway if I do this I get some error:  `error: C:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/node-ltp.lua:3148: attempt to index local 'hlist' (a number value)` the moment I use a bit longer text (ie one that actually does some breaking into lines) and with the text above you still get `Lua linebreak_filter failed, reverting to default on line 1` so what comes out is probably from the internal parabuilder not the lua code

Comment: I have updated the answer to add the \starttext wrapper. I assume a next ConTeXt beta will have the bug fixed, and hopefully that will then appear in TL. And yes, when you see the 'reverted' line the output comes from the internal par builder

Comment: hope one day we'll have a workable solution out of the box but for now it seems this is the best approximation

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: FWIW, the code posted by Taco works with a recent ConTeXt installation.

Comment: @Aditya yes and no ... it does run that's true but if you set \tracingparagraphs and \tracingonline you see that it still has some problems as it reports several times "Lua linebreak_filter failed, reverting to default on line 1". This is not during the main para breaking (that gets executed using the lua implementation it seems) but in other places -- not yet traced.