# How to use luatex's node.hpack so that marks, inserts and vadjusts migrate out?

Tags: luatex, paragraphs, lua

TeX's hpack routine packages an hlist into a box. While doing that it looks at a global pointer `adjust_tail` and if that is not  "null" it migrates some nodes to a separate list starting at `adjust_head`. This way material from `\mark`, `\insert` or `\vadjust` migrates out from the line into the enclosing vertical list during the paragraph building. Otherwise they stay inside the box.

From the luatex manual I was unable to see how this effect could be achieved using `node.hpack`. Luatex knows `tex.lists.adjust_head` and `tex.lists.pre_adjust_head`(whatever that is?) but I couldn't quite see if they correspond to TeX's `adjust_head` and `adjust_tail`or how to indicate that `node.hpack`should do the migrating.

If it can at all (the manual has some notes on `node.hpack` having weird side-effects on `\insert` and such in some cases).

Reason I'm interested in that is to write my own paragraph builder or adapting Taco's code (that doesn't seem to work in that respect (see question [Replacement(s) for TeX's paragraph builder using LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200989/10109)) and has a few other bugs so that it currently doesn't quite work.

Of course, if worst comes to worst, I guess I could migrate those nodes out manually prior to calling `node.hpack` but if possible I would use the internal and have it done for me as that is most certainly faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LuaTeX's `adjust_head` corresponds to TeX's `adjust_head` and setting it automatically sets `adjust_tail` to the end of the `adjust_head` list, even if it is empty(`nil`).
So if you have a  `hlist` and want to apply `node.hpack` while letting things migrate out, you first set `adjust_head` (and therefore also `adjust_tail` to an empty list:

```
tex.lists.adjust_head = nil
tex.lists.pre_adjust_head = nil
```

Then `node.hpack` deletes all migrateable nodes from the list and moves them into the nodelist `tex.lists.adjust_head`. From there you can handle them as you wish.

Here `pre_adjust_head` works just like `adjust_head`: It is used to implement the pdfTeX extension `\vadjust pre{stuff}` which inserts `stuff` *before* instead of *after* the line where `\vadjust` appears.

So to emulate normal TeX behavior, first the `pre_adjust_head` list has to be inserted into the outer `vlist`, than the result from `hpack`and finally `adjust_head`.

To clean up at the end of your code you might want to reset `tex.lists.adjust_head` and `tex.lists.pre_adjust_head`.
Setting them to `nil` would just create an empty list and this would stop TeX from keeping any migrateable material in a `hbox`. Sadly I do not think there is a way to manually set the interal TeX values to `null`, so we need a trick:
`tex.linebreak` works with this lists and resets them at the end, so you just have to call `tex.linebreak`. We do not actually want to break a line so we can pass an empty `hlist` node to avoid too much work while still triggering the side effect of cleaning up the `adjust_` lists:

```
tex.linebreak(node.new'hlist')
```

Comment: The trick you mention at the end seems to indicate that LuaTeX is missing some more decent interface in that space, doesn't it?