# Can LuaTeX change the PAGE-breaking algorithm

Tags: page-breaking, luatex

One of the often highlighted features in LuaTeX is the ability to replace the default TeX line-breaking algorithm by something else. **I wonder if it is similarly possible to replace the *page*-breaking algorithm?** This would be a great feature, since the page-breaking algorithm in TeX is often described as more "greedy" than the line-breaking algorithm, and as not very good at optimizing globally.

**EDIT:** *If* this turns out to be possible, can this be used to solve the following problem, highlighted by [Frank Mittelbach](http://latex-project.org/papers/tb106mittelbach-e-tex-revisited.pdf)? I assume no, since Frank does not state so explicitly.

> #### Issue: TEX generates pages based on precompiled paragraph data
>
> This issue describes the fundamental problem in TeX’s approach: the program builds optimized paragraph shapes without any knowledge about their final
>   placement on a page. The result is a “galley” from which columns are cut to a specified vertical size. A consequence of this is that one can’t have the shape
>   of a paragraph depend on its final position on the page when using TEX’s page builder algorithm.
>
> To some extent, it is possible to program around this limitation, e.g., by measuring the remaining space on a page and explicitly changing paragraph shapes after determining where the current textual material will finally appear. However, besides being complicated to implement, it requires accounting for all kinds of special situations that normally would be automatically managed by TEX, and providing “programmed” solutions for them.
>
> As a result, all attempts so far to provide such functionality had to impose strong limitations on the allowed input material, i.e., they worked only in restricted setups and even then, the results were often not satisfactory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, see the documentation of the `buildpage_filter` callback, and possibly also the `pre_output_filter` callback.

Note however that unlike the linebreaking algorithm, there are very few parts of the page breaker that you are forced to use directly, which is why different strategies can be programmed even in classic tex without needing lua extensions, such as two column mode in standard latex, or multicol package.

Comment: So this issue significant issue in TeX may actually be solved completely? `:-D`

Comment: @Gaussler I don't understand the comment (or the question).

Comment: You answered the question exactly. I'm talking about applications now. [Frank Mittelbach](http://latex-project.org/papers/tb106mittelbach-e-tex-revisited.pdf) highlights some of the issues of page-breaking in LaTeX; I wonder if this callback can be used to solve this?

Comment: @Gaussler It's important to note that LaTeX will *never* rely on LuaTeX.

Comment: Who decides that? Mittelbach? Lamport? Knuth? God? (Defintely not Knuth.)

Comment: @Gaussler God. :-) Those of you actually *on* the LaTeX project, forgive me if I'm speaking out of line, but LaTeX won't rely on something that not everybody has or is willing to use. LaTeX assumes TeX and only TeX. (Well, at this point that's been extended to e-TeX, but that's something that everyone uses now, anyway.)

Comment: @SeanAllred I know that is the current position. But never say never. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler don't count on it :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred We are basically stuck nowadays with 'LaTeX = LaTeX2e' and the team are not going make any change to the engine requirements for 2e.

Comment: @JosephWright, I thought you were aiming at 'LaTeX = LaTeX3'. Have you given up on that already? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Not given up, but it's clear that `latex` as a command will have to stay as LaTeX2e

Comment: @JosephWright Then you should come up with a new name instead of LaTeX3. If you hurry, you might be able to convince the others to call it WriTeX. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler If we want to kill the project stone dead, yes. Otherwise we _need_ the LaTeX name. This is an important and tricky area: if you want to discuss it, LaTeX-L is the place.

Comment: @Gaussler: You mean something like "ConTeXt MkIV"? :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Never heard of it. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, also, see my updated question about the applications of this feature.

Comment: @Gaussler you need a different callback for that (but as far as we know no one managed to use it successfully) Frank has a question about that, I'll find it in a bit...

Comment: @Gaussler see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200989/replacements-for-texs-paragraph-builder-using-luatex

Comment: So I guess that means there is hope this issue of TeX *can* be solved. `:-D`

Comment: @Gaussler you can solve it in classic tex as well, it's just tricky but things have shown it's not necessarily easier in lua