# Is Lua(La)TeX going to implement a better page breaking algorithm

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, typography

recently I found that LuaTeX can allow for the implementation of a new page breaking algorithm, substituting the TeX paragraph-based one. (see [Can LuaTeX change the PAGE-breaking algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250061/can-luatex-change-the-page-breaking-algorithm))

Since I had some typesetting problems in a book I recently finished, I'm asking if ever the page breaking algorithm will be enhanced, since now the memory limitations of the original TeX era have subsided.

I understand the greediness of the algorithm ([Why no vertical mode Knuth-Plass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/why-no-vertical-mode-knuth-plass)), but it's really still impossible? Or is it something that is not seen as a priority? Or maybe, when running LuaTeX, the engine is already triyng an optimized page breaking algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems rather broad. It would help if you could point out either some specific shortcomings with Plass-Knuth that you perceive to be major problems or some speicific objectives that aren't met by Plass-Knuth.

Comment: See the talk of Frank Mittelbach at the TUG Conference 2016 about "Alice goes floating" https://www.latex-project.org/publications/#publications-in-2016 and also his paper https://dl.acm.org/authorize?N12887

Comment: @Mico I'm not saying that the Plass-Knuth algorithm has any shortcomings. Merely I say that there is no vertical mode Knuth-Plass

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I'll do that immediately